# XSLT Tag Insert

Tags: xslt, insert, attributes

I have a multi level block of XML, my requirement is to inject a new Scenario tag per Employee block. The value within the new Scenario tag can change based on the value in the Event tag

FROM

```
<Extract>
    <Header>
        <Date1>01/01/2020</Date1>
    </Header>
    <Employee>
        <Status>
            <Event>Event_1</Event>
        </Status>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Status>
            <Event>Event_2</Event>
        </Status>
    </Employee>
</Extract>
```

TO

```
<Extract>
    <Header>
        <Date1>01/01/2020</Date1>
    </Header>
    <Employee>
        <Status>
            <Event>Event_1</Event>
        </Status>
        <Scenario>A</Scenario>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Status>
            <Event>Event_2</Event>
        </Status>
        <Scenario>B</Scenario>
    </Employee>
</Extract>
```

I have been playing around with this, I am able to successfully get the tag inserted, but before the tag is added in I am looking to have a choose statement to determine the desired output in the tag. As below

```
<xsl:param name="to-insert"> 
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="Employee/Status/Event = 'Event_1' ">
                <Scenairo>A</Scenairo>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="Employee/Status/Event = 'Event_2' ">
                <Scenairo>B</Scenairo>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <Scenairo><xsl:value-of select="'no scenario mapped'"/></Scenairo>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:param>

<!-- Copy all sections of XML -->
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/> 
         <xsl:copy-of select="$to-insert"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: All feedback & pointers are most welcome. I think when I pass the node to the param there are no tags it is just the raw values in a continuous string, so it can't evaluate anything, always falls into xsl:otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> always falls into xsl:otherwise

No, but it only evaluates the first `Employee` (in XSLT 1.0] or all employees together (in XSLT 2.0).

If you can have more than one `Employee` you need to calculate the value of `Scenario` from the context of `Employee` - for example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
        <Scenario>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="Status/Event = 'Event_1'">A</xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="Status/Event = 'Event_2'">B</xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>no scenario mapped</xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </Scenario>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: That is perfect yes, it works a treat. I think I was trying to be too fancy with my approach.

Comment: Sincere apologies, but I have been informed that Employee is not the root node of the XML, it is something more like

FROM
`code xml <Extract>
   <Header>
      <Date1></Date1>
   </Header>
   <Employee>
     <Status>
        <Event>Event_1</Event>
     </Status>
   </Employee>
</Extract>`


TO
`code xml <Extract>
   <Header>
      <Date1></Date1>
   </Header>
   <Employee>
     <Status>
        <Event>Event_1</Event>
     </Status>
     <Scenario>A</Scenario>
   </Employee>
</Extract>`

Comment: I didn't think Employee was the root element - otherwise your code would have worked. So what is the problem? Use the above template in addition to the identity transform template which you already have. -- P.S. Please do not post code in comments; if necessary, edit your question.

Comment: Sorry I have the originally post update now with the full XML

Comment: I have added a full XSLT that produces the requested result.

Comment: Yes, I did this myself offline, thanks for the steer on the Emplyee match template.